# pandas groupby with subgroup operations like determinants?

Tags: python, regression, pandas-groupby

I'm doing fat *regressions* recently, so I moved from R to python, everything works fine but I run into the *'Singular Matrix'* (due to multicollinearity or perfect predictability) error a lot. This is not an issue in R or Stata as they drop observations like that automatically, so I actually have two questions:

1. is there a built-in way in python to deal with 'Singular Matrix' error caused by the two sources I just mentioned?
2. if not, I want to pick out those observations by myself, but got a problem in trying.

The basic idea, for each subgroup (as I use lots fixed effect), calculates determinants of correlations, drop those subgroups whose value are low enough.

**My data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'col_2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'col_3':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
                   'col_4':0*10})
```

**My regression equation:**

```
col_4 ~ col_1 + col_2 + C(col_3)
```

determinants of each group:

```
np.linalg.det(np.corrcoef(df.loc[df['col_3'].isin(['A'])][['col_1','col_2','col_4']]))
2.068910295301473e-48
np.linalg.det(np.corrcoef(df.loc[df['col_3'].isin(['B'])][['col_1','col_2','col_4']]))
8.197321048400957e-50
```

**What I want**

```
 col_1  col_2 col_3  col_4       col_det
0      1      1     A      0  2.068910e-48
1      1      2     A      0  2.068910e-48
2      1      3     A      0  2.068910e-48
3      1      4     A      0  2.068910e-48
4      1      5     A      0  2.068910e-48
5      2      6     B      0  8.197321e-50
6      2      7     B      0  8.197321e-50
7      2      8     B      0  8.197321e-50
8      2      9     B      0  8.197321e-50
9      2     10     B      0  8.197321e-50
```